# Three.js Maths conversion

Tags: javascript, math, three.js

Not being very good at maths, I'm struggling with this.

I've got a conversion of lat/lon into a target:

```
    lat = Math.max(-85, Math.min(85, lat));
    phi = THREE.Math.degToRad(90 - lat);
    theta = THREE.Math.degToRad(lon);

    target.x = 512 * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
    target.y = 512 * Math.cos(phi);
    target.z = 512 * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);
```

Can anyone tell me how I would reverse that, i.e. convert a Vector into lat/lon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this

```
var lat = Math.atan2( Math.sqrt( target.x*target.x + target.z*target.z) , target.y) ;
var lon = Math.atan2( target.x, target.y);
```

Suggestion:

Checkout wikipedia for these functions, i believe the diagram will make perfect sense.